# Delete a JSON object from a file on discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

I've searched for a very long time on every site I can get my hands on. Each provided no help and left me with the same issue of the object remains. The code for the command is [here](https://github.com/NineTailedTaviChan/area-17/blob/master/commands/characters/remove.js) and the JSON file I am attempting to modify is [here](https://github.com/NineTailedTaviChan/area-17/blob/master/characters.json). Is there a solution for this? I've added a temporary one where I have to manually remove it myself by the bot DMing me with a request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [edit-json-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/edit-json-file) package from NPM.

It has an "`unset(path)` **Remove a path from a JSON object.**" method.

An example can be:

```js
const editJsonFile = require("edit-json-file");
let file = editJsonFile("C:/Users/worko/Desktop/GitHub/area-17/characters.json");

//Put your discord code here

file.unset("Tavi-chan Wood");
//or
file.unset("Tavi-chan Wood.content");

file.save();
```